# put a server application on a real server

Tags: c#, service, server

I made a simple server, that is running locally using tcplisten.
This server works fine over local network.
I want to put this program on a real server so, people will be able to connect to it from different computers.

I understand that maybe i will need to make a service out of it.

The question is how do i put the service/program on a real server, what steps I need to take?

I am familiar only with building a site and uploading it to some host. but i have no idea how to do it with a program.

Comment: By purchasing website hosting, you only rent an IIS server and don't get access to the rest of the machine. You want to host an application, so you'll have to rent an entire machine. Either choose an entire Virtual Machine or look at Azure. But I'm sure this is better explained in existing questions, did you try searching?

Comment: yes, but i didn't find much. maybe i used a bad keywords. I'll search more information about Azure and an entire virtual machine renting. Thank you.

Comment: Does this program run as a service? Or are you running it as a simple command line app in Visual Studio?

Comment: Generally networking configuration is off-topic for SO. In current form your post is way too broad as it may range from "how to expose my server to internet (port forwarding)" to "what is the best hosting provider". None of the possible interpretations of your question can be answered with code...

Comment: @matrixugly i am running it a simple command line app but i think i can easily make it a service.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I read about port forwarding. and i am asking more about how to put the application to run as a server app in a real server - (not using my computer). I am familiar with site hosting. but i have no idea when it comes to running an application on a server. Yes the answer will not contain code, is it wrong to post such questions?

Comment: possible duplicate question and answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3129527/2437521

Comment: @matrixugly - I don't think it is related at all... This one about finding looks like about finding good hosting provider and steps to deploy, the one you've linked - about converting service to normal exe.

Comment: @user3478552 there is really no such thing as "real server" :) You need to figure out what you really need and how much you want to pay for it. Than find provider that satisfy your requirement (maybe VM solutions from Microsoft Azure/Amazon EC2/... or something else). There are really thousands of providers and tens of different deployment approaches.

Comment: @user3478552 - "the answer will not contain code, is it wrong to post such questions" - not necessary, but it is very good indication that post likely will be off-topic on SO.